# Adding Arrays Based On Variable Number Index Value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get indVars to repeat for the amount of times that numInd requires. So if numInd = 3 then I'm wanting something similar to this indVars[0] = divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd -- indVars[1] = divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd ... and so on for however many numInd dictates --- Then the arrays get posted to innerHTML.

```
/*User Selection Of Indicators*/
var numInd = 3 /*This is amount of indicators that should show in innerHTML.*/

/*User Entry Variables Per Selection*/
var uHeight = 120
var uWidth = 225

/*Html Variables*/
var divStart = '<div class="col-sm-auto">'
var userEntryVars = '<img src="whatever.jpg" style="height:' + uHeight +'px; width: '+ uWidth + 'px">'
var divEnd = '</div>'

/*Div InnerHTML*/
var divArea = document.getElementById("IndicatorArea") ;
var out = []
var indVars = [divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd] ;
/*Loop For Number Of Indicators*/
for (i = 0; i < numInd; i++){
 out.push(indVars[i])
};
console.log(out[0]) /*Returns Data I Expect*/
console.log(out[1]) /*Returns Data I Don't Expect, It Should Be Showing Same as out[0]*/
divArea.InnerHTML = indVars
```

So the user selects the amount of indicators that should show (indicators = boxes), then they can type in the variables that go into the innerHTML...so if they select 2, the user has to fill in 2 of the user entries for each variable because the indicators will show different data. I have tried a few variations of arrays and I have gotten close but sometimes I'm getting "undefined" and then the div counts. I'm thinking the HTML Variables should be in a for loop to loop for the number of indicators but I'm not sure. Ultimately, the number of selected indicators should be 3 different entities, and within these 3 different entities can be variable data posted by the user. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by the following code.

```
/*User Selection Of Indicators*/
var numInd = 3 /*This is amount of indicators that should show in innerHTML.*/

/*User Entry Variables Per Selection*/
var uHeight = 120
var uWidth = 225

/*Html Variables*/
var divStart = '<div class="col-sm-auto">'
var userEntryVars = '<img src="whatever.jpg" style="height:' + uHeight +'px; width: '+ uWidth + 'px">'
var divEnd = '</div>'

/*Div InnerHTML*/
var divArea = document.getElementById("IndicatorArea") ;
var out = []
var indVars = divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd ;
/*Loop For Number Of Indicators*/
for (i = 0; i < numInd; i++){
 out.push(indVars)
};
divArea.InnerHTML = out.join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

for `indVars`, right now you're adding together `divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd`.

If you want `indVars[0] = divStart` and `indVars[1] = userEntryVars`, declare it like

`var indVars = [divStart, userEntryVars, divEnd]`

Comment: I would like indVars = that whole section. I am trying to basically get indVars to repeat for the amount of times that numInd requires. So if numInd = 3 then I'm wanting something similar to this indVars[0] = divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd -- indVars[1] = divStart + userEntryVars + divEnd ... and so on for however many numInd dictates